# Insert a 2 joined collections to a new collection MongoDB with javascript

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to join two collection to a new collection while inserting the result to the new collection.

The code I use for join:

```
db.users.aggregate(
  [{
    $lookup: {
      from: "posts",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "_uid",
      as: "postsByUser"
    }
  }])
```

I know that this returns a new collection/array
Now,I can insert this new array into a new collection like this:

```
db.postsByUsers.insert(db.users.aggregate(
  [{
    $lookup: {
      from: "posts",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "_uid",
      as: "postsByUser"
    }
  }]))
```

But the result it that im getting in the collection "postsByUsers" isn't what I was expecting.
I get alot of additional field like: _useReadCommands,_cursorid,_batchSize etc.
I do get the information I need in the field called _batch but its not as clean as I expected, I want it to look like an array with objects inside of it + the postsByUser field at the end that will give me all the Information. As im testing this with trying to set a `var` usersPosts that equal to the join coding I did and looping through it and For each doc: `db.postsByUsers.insert(usersPosts)` that seems to do nothing:

```
usersPosts.forEach(function(doc){
  db.postsByUsers.insertOne(doc)
})
```

The weird thing that I did manage to get the result I wanted but I don't know why(weird), I tried to go through the code I wrote With pressing the up key on the cmd bvut nothing seems to give me the same result...Please help and thank you so much for Reading!

Comment: Could you share the schema, the current output ( json format ) and expected output?

Comment: I can send a file with all the information if you want to get a better perspective, because Thats alot of information :)

Comment: You don't need to send the whole file, just the minimum part that is relevant. We would like to know the structure of `users` and `posts`. I have posted an answer below, please add a comment if the answer still doesn't solve your question :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) aggregation pipeline stage to output the result of an aggregation pipeline into another collection

```
{ $out: 'postsByUsers' }
```

From MongoDB 4.2 onwards you can also use [$merge](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/), which is more flexible and can merge the result documents with existing ones.

Comment: Thank you for replying! can you be more specific about where should I put { $out: 'postsByUsers' } inside db.users.aggregate(
  [{
    $lookup: {
      from: "posts",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "_uid",
      as: "postsByUser"
    }
  }])

Comment: Please consult the documentation I refer to. It should be put your last stage of aggregation, that would be `.aggregate([{ $lookup: {...} }, { $out: ... } ])`

Comment: Holy, it actually worked, thank you so much for the big help, I was stuck on this for too much long! hope you have a good day/night!